# ¿Como filtrar que el nombre de un archivo no supere un largo de caracteres en el navegador ni en PHP?

Tags: php, html

Quiero guardar en una columna de una base de datos el nombre de un archivo PDF.  El nombre de la columna es `nombre_pdf` con un `varchar(50)` y el problema que tengo es que si el `nombre_pdf` rebasa el límite de 50 caracteres, no se guardará todo el nombre.

Sé que con la función `substr` de PHP se puede hacer, pero no sé en dónde puedo emplearla: si en el formulario, en la función donde se realiza la inserción a la base de datos, la siguiente función es donde inserta a la base de datos:

```
public function registro( $nombre_pdf, $autor, $fecha, $archivo, $carrera ){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tesis ( nombre_pdf, autor,
    fecha, archivo, carrera ) VALUES ( '$nombre_pdf', '$autor', '$fecha', '$archivo', '$carrera' )";
    $consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
    echo '<script language="javascript">
            alert("Los datos se registraron con exito");
            window.location.href="index.php";
          </script>';
}
```

Comment: ¿El nombre que se guarda en la base de datos incluye la extensión `.pdf`?

Comment: Creo que entonces deberías de validar que el nombre que ingresen en el formulario o de donde sea que lo estés obteniendo no exceda los 50 caracteres.

Comment: No tiene sentido que uses `substr` si tienes configurado MySQL para que omita el exceso de caracteres (como parece que indicas), porque entonces hacer `substr` o no hacerlo va a acabar con el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo que no dejes al usuario escribir desde el formulario más de 50 caracteres. Para ello, no necesitarás ninguna función de PHP si no que lo podrás hacer directamente desde el propio input con el atributo `maxlength`.

Ejemplo:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" maxlength="50">
</form>
```

Sin embargo, como en el lado del cliente el HTML puede ser modificado es conveniente que también uses la comprobación mediante PHP. Para asegurarte, como muy bien dices, puedes usar la función `substr`, aunque la tendrías que realizar antes de realizar el INSERT para que no te de problemas al insertarlo a la base de datos.

```
public function registro( $nombre_pdf, $autor, $fecha, $archivo, $carrera ){
    $nombre_pdf = substr($nombre_pdf, -1, 50);
    //Aquí iría tu INSERT
}
```

Si te fijas, en el segundo parámetro utilizo el -1 para que empiece por el final y de esta manera también contenga la extensión `.pdf` y que no te de problemas a la hora de hacer referencia al fichero después.

Comment: +1 porque el usuario tiene que saber que su nombre de archivo esta cortado, y el sistema tambien que lo corto...

Comment: @Francisco Romero, controlar lo que el usuario mete en el formulario es el primer paso, pero estas medidas de seguridad se pueden saltar con facilidad. **Los datos que llegan de un formulario deben ser controlados SIEMPRE en el servidor**.

Comment: @Orici Por eso he añadido la segunda parte de la respuesta en la que indico como hacer la comprobación con PHP para mayor seguridad advirtiéndole del peligro de hacerlo en el lado del cliente: _"Sin embargo, como en el lado del cliente el HTML puede ser modificado..."_

Comment: @Francisco Romero no lo había visto. No se si aun no lo habías añadido o no lo leí. Me parece una puntualización importante.

Comment: @Orici No te preocupes. Lo añadí desde el inicio ya que me parece un tema importante en cuanto a seguridad. Lo único que para la gente nueva el tema de cliente/servidor igual no queda tan sobreentendido. Igual debería especificar que hay que hacer la comprobación desde el mismo.

Comment: @Francisco Romero muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudo a resolver el problema, lo puse tal cual me indicaste en mi función y funciono, me has salvado de mi problema, mil gracias....

Answer (score 0):

La lógica por la que sólo puedes almacenar un nombre de hasta 50 caracteres pertenecería a la parte del modelo y aunque deberías pasar los datos "preparados" al método `"registro()"`, sería "apropiado" preparar el largo de ese nombre en el propio método antes de montar la *INSERT*.

En realidad deberías usar un método privado de la clase para hacer eso, o mejor que te crees uno en una clase de tipo *helper* (que podrías nombrar **StringTools**, por ejemplo) con la finalidad de preparar el nombre en caso de que sea demasiado largo (e incluso si no es así).

Un método que adecue el nombre del fichero te puede permitir; conservar letras en lugar de espacios, sustuir espacios por guiones, sustituir eñes por enes o quitar acentos (menos problemas futuros), etc. Además es recomendable usar **mb_substr()** en lugar de **substr()**, que no va a cortar tus 50 caracteres si encuentra acentos, eñes, etc...
Puedes ver la documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-substr.php

Y tu método quedaría así:

```
public function registro( $nombre_pdf, $autor, $fecha, $archivo, $carrera ) {

    $nombre_pdf = StringTools::prepareFileName( $nombre_pdf );

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tesis ( 
        nombre_pdf, 
        autor,
        fecha, 
        archivo, 
        carrera 
    ) VALUES ( 
        '$nombre_pdf', 
        '$autor', 
        '$fecha', 
        '$archivo', 
        '$carrera' 
    )";
    $consulta = $this->conecta()->query( $sql );

    echo '<script language="javascript">
            alert("Los datos se registraron con exito");
            window.location.href="index.php";
          </script>';
}
```

Y **StringTools::prepareFileName()** tendría como objeto cambiar algo como esto:

```
"Éste puede ser un nombre demasiado largo para almacenar"
```

por esto otro:

```
"EstePuedeSerUnNombreDemasiadoLargoParaAlmacenar"
```

Escribirlo en otra clase te permitirá usarlo desde otros puntos de tu aplicación y llevarlo con facilidad a otros proyectos.

Una cosa que no me gusta, aunque no es parte de la pregunta es que tengas código de la vista (el alert) en el método que esta almacenando información en la BD, te recomiendo estudiar el **patrón MVC**. A éste respecto tu método podría devolver un booleano y generar un *'feedback'* donde corresponda.

Saludos.